# Pandas Using Unique row value as columns like pivot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

dataset: top 50 novels sold each years
Genre column: fiction , nonfiction (only two unique values)

how can I summarize data so that I  get a table of author name, and the number of fiction And nonfiction books they have written in two different columns ?

Here is the minimized version of dataset:

"""{**'Name'**: {0: '10-Day Green Smoothie Cleanse',
1: '11/22/63: A Novel',
2: '12 Rules for Life: An Antidote to Chaos'},

**'Author**': {0: 'JJ Smith', 1: 'Stephen King', 2: 'Jordan B. Peterson'},

**'User Rating'**: {0: 4.7, 1: 4.6, 2: 4.7},

**'Reviews'**: {0: '17,350', 1: '2,052', 2: '18,979'},

**'Price'**: {0: '$8.00', 1: '$22.00', 2: '$15.00'},

**'Price_r'**: {0: '$8', 1: '$22', 2: '$15'},

**'Year'**: {0: 2016, 1: 2011, 2: 2018},

**'Genre'**: {0: 'Non Fiction', 1: 'Fiction', 2: 'Non Fiction'}} """

```
df.groupby(['Author']).Genre.value_counts().sort_values(ascending  =  False)
```

I have tried using group by but not getting sperate columns for fiction and non fiction.

Comment: could you provide an example, to test our solutions please

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture. E.g. try `df.to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output. Also, show us what you have tried so far, and why your attempt isn't giving you the result that you expect. See: [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: pls have a look at it now

Answer (score -1):

We dont have the column's names but from what I understand, something like this should do the work :

```
df.groupby(["author", "genre"]).count()
```

Or (to get back the "author" and "genre" as columns instead of having them in the index) :

```
df.groupby(["author", "genre"]).count().reset_index()
```